# questioning a proposed method for demonstrating the consistency of two propositions

Tags: logic

I am trying to wrap my head around the following proposed method for showing that two propositions are consistent:

> Now one way to show that a proposition *p* is consistent with a proposition *q* is to produce a third proposition *r* whose conjunction with *p* is consistent and entails *q*.  *r*, of course, need not be true or known to be true; it need not be so much as plausible.  All that is required of it is that it be consistent with *p*, and in conjunction with the latter entail *q* (Plantinga, *The Nature of Necessity*, 1974, p.165).

A problem I am envisioning for this method is a case where *p* and *q* are individually consistent, but jointly inconsistent.  Following Plantinga's reasoning we could adopt the following candidate for *r*:  a material conditional with *p* as antecedent, *q* as consequent.  This conditional will be consistent with *p*, and in conjunction with the latter entails *q*.  Despite their assumed joint inconsistency, we can follow Plantinga's method and show *p* and *q* to be consistent.

Is this a genuine concern for the proposed method, or am I overlooking something?  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you overlooked something. If $p,q$ are jointly inconsistent, then it cannot be that $p \land (p \to q)$ is consistent, otherwise it would entail $p \land q$ by conjunction elimination and modus ponens, which is by assumption inconsistent. Therefore you cannot to derive a contradiction via Plantinga's method.

Comment: You've confirmed the OP's concerns: Plantinga's argument is nonsense when interpreted in with any reasonable notion of consistency, conjunction and entailment for precisely the reasons you suggest.

Comment: @RobArthan: Sorry but your comment is false. I'm saying that Pantinga's reasoning is fine and it's the **asker** who overlooked something.

Comment: so please cite an example of $p$, $q$ and $r$ where Plantinga's remarks are not vacuous.

Comment: @RobArthan: You said that it is nonsense. **That** is false. Whether or not it is vacuous is another matter altogether. It may indeed be easier to find such an $r$ as Plantinga's method requires (note that he said it's one way, not necessarily always a useful way) than to directly prove consistency of $p+q$, and even though one can unravel that proof to get a 'direct' proof it may not be as illuminating. I believe I've seen a few instances of such a technique, but it will take me a while to recall them.